# python read file by column without loading into memory?

Tags: python, csv, hadoop, azure-hdinsight, pearson

I have a csv file that contains about 400 columns +100.000 lines.
I m trying to run MapReduce job in HDinsight Hadoop Cluster.
The Logic of my MapReduce is calculating Peason's correlation matrix.

The map operation generates every possible pair of values along with each key.

**Example :**
Given this as input :

```
1,2,3
4,5,6
```

The Mapper output would be :

```
keys   pairs
0,1    1,2
0,2    1,3
1,2    2,3
0,1    4,5
0,2    4,6
1,2    5,6
```

As you can conclude that the size of the mapper output depends much more on the number of columns so on the complexity of Sort phase. Which i think why my mapreduce job fails.

I used to output the complete lists in previous mapper scripts like this :

```
keys   pairs
0,1    1,2,4,5
0,2    1,3,4,6
1,2    2,3,5,6
```

but this needs a complete read of the file in order to zip it and then zip each pair of columns. In this case i run out of memory if the file is sufficiently large.

I though about reading columns instead of lines and keep using "yield" to optimize both memory usage in mapper and sort.

**Is there a way to read a file column by column (given a certain separator) without loading it completely into the memory ?**

Comment: Maybe memory mapped IO using the `mmap` module could help to get around the problem of loading the file completely into working memory?

Comment: Read, How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve